# Run a method before each Action in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

How can we run a method before running each Action in MVC3?

I know we can use the following method for `OnActionExecuting` :

```
public class ValidateUserSessionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

But how can we run a method before ActionExecuting ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for [Controller.ExecuteCore()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.executecore%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

This function is called before each action calls. You can override it in a controller or a base controller. Example that sets culture base on cookies from [Nadeem Afana](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx):

```
   public class BaseController : Controller
   {
      protected override void ExecuteCore()
      {
         string cultureName = null;
         // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
         HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
         if (cultureCookie != null)
         {
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
         }
         else
         {
            if (Request.UserLanguages != null)
            {
               cultureName = Request.UserLanguages[0]; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages
            }
            else 
            {
               cultureName = "en-US"; // Default value
            }
         }

         // Validate culture name
         cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe


         // Modify current thread's cultures            
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

         base.ExecuteCore();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Override BeginExecute if you need it everywhere. i.e.: File upload

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest looking into AOP, [Postsharp](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-samples/) or [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) can easily handle such as task.

Answer (score 3):

Also you could consider use Application_BeginRequest method in global.asax

Comment: I need to use `Request.Cookies` and `Session` in the method. but we can't access them in `Application_BeginRequest`