# Running a method from your baseController within all actionMethods in controllers that inherit the baseController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Currently I have a `baseController` that has a method called `PrepareData`. All other controllers that inherit this `baseController` is currently running `PrepareData` in every action method. If `PrepareData is not ran the page will crash due to missing information.

I am trying to narrow down a solution that will allow me to run `PrepareData` without explicitly calling it in every action method. I have been thinking of using custom attributes, but I think that would still require me to either put it on top of every class or on top of every action method.

Base Controller:

```
void PrepareData(int a, string b, string c, string d)
{
     ViewBag.Provinces = a;
     ViewBag.CompetencyEmploymentTypes = b;
     ViewBag.ExpertiseTypes = c;
     ViewBag.Countries = d;
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ListExams(string id)
{
     PrepareData(1,id,"Exams","Exams");
     // Do something 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a method before each Action in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830394/run-a-method-before-each-action-in-mvc3)

Comment: Where do the values of those parameters come from?

Comment: It will come from the controller and some hard coded values depending on the action.